# get column name by index and use in mysql query

Tags: mysql, select, indexing, information-schema

I need query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE owner_field = 100
```

But "owner_field" is different in several tables. I want to use index for field's identification:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_NAME=table AND INDEX_NAME='owner') = 100
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I want do add this condition to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries for security control (user can do anything only with his own data).

Mysql structure like this:

```
user_id     
post_id        post_author    = user_id
category_id    category_owner = user_id
```

Comment: I really don't think you can use the results of a query as the name of a column. Also, this looks like terrible design.

Answer (score 0):

This is terrible design, and most likely impossible.

Why not use a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html)?

```
CREATE VIEW table1_ownerfield AS SELECT ownerfield_1 FROM table1;
CREATE VIEW table2_ownerfield AS SELECT ownerfield_2 FROM table2;
```

Then you use them as the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM table1_ownerfield;
SELECT * FROM table2_ownerfield;
```

For the second part of your question, look at using [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html).

Edit:

It sounds like the kind of view that you want is something like:

```
CREATE VIEW my_posts AS 
    SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_owner = CURRENT_USER() 
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
CREATE VIEW my_categories AS 
    SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_owner = CURRENT_USER() 
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

You probably want to do something like this:

Create a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE user_connections (
     user_connection_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     mysql_connection_id INT,
     user_id INT
 );
```

Then when a user logs in, populate this table with the mysql connection ID using the function [`CONNECTION_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id).

Then you can create the views like:

```
CREATE VIEW my_posts AS 
    SELECT * FROM posts p JOIN user_connections uc 
    WHERE uc.mysql_connection_id = CONNECTION_ID() 
    AND p.post_user_id = uc.user_id 
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
CREATE VIEW my_categories AS 
    SELECT * FROM categories c JOIN user_connections uc 
    WHERE uc.mysql_connection_id = CONNECTION_ID() 
    AND c.category_user_id = uc.user_id 
    WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot!
Is better to do this when user log in? And view name can be setted like 'user_id'_posts?

Comment: Or better use another way: json config like this: data {table:post, id:post_id, owner:post_author}

Comment: I checked, thx. I need to learn more about this in the manual, because my knowledge base is too small. I write this just for training.
But how about memory|disk|etc use if I'll have many users logged? 10 users need 20 views only for posts and categories.

Comment: @user1781280 no. You do not need 2 views for every user. You have two views total.

Comment: Uhh... Is "views" dynamically tables, created on query like "SELECT FROM my_posts"?

Comment: @user1781280 pretty much. I recommend reading the documentation for VIEWs and perhaps some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an easier way:

```
CREATE VIEW indexed_posts AS 
SELECT * FROM posts, users
WHERE post_author = user_id 
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Then I can use query:

```
SELECT * FROM indexed_posts WHERE user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```